# Finding pattern of lines of a file, print lines until first empty line

Tags: observer-pattern, empty-list

I have a file whith headers of a data, and another whith more information for all that headers. So, I need first, read line by line of the header's file and next to find that line in a other file, and if pattern is found, copy that lines and next lines until the first empty line in a new file.

I've been trying this:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname1= header.txt
fname2= complete-data.txt
cat $fname1 | while read -r line; do
    echo $line
    sed -n "$line/,/^ *$/p" $fname2 > new-file.txt
done
```

but it is not working:

```
sed: can't read line/,/^ *$/p: No such file or directory
```

when I copy a line and I do it manually, it works:

```
sed -n 'line_to_find/,/^ *$/p2' complete-data.txt > new-file.txt
```

Help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

First, add a `/` at the beginning of your pattern.

Second, you are overwriting your output on each iteration.
Do your I/O control at the end of the loop:

```
$: cat header.txt
2    
4

$: cat complete-data.txt
1
this is #1
just #1

2
this is #2
just #2

3
this is #3
just #3

4
this is #4
just #4

5
this is #5
just #5

$: while read -r line
   do sed -n "/$line/,/^ *$/p" complete-data.txt
   done < header.txt > new-file.txt

$: cat new-file.txt
2
this is #2
just #2

4
this is #4
just #4
```

Comment: This did not work for me, below I explain my problem better...

Answer (score 0):

Since I wrote the question, I realized that I was missing the /.
But, is steel not working!! I thought it could be the spaces, but I already fixed that problem and it still doesn't work...

This is my real case:

**header.txt**

```
2019  11 16 46   6.4183 -29.23337  -71.06854   5.0000 NOEVID          0.116     5.612   4.0   5.0  20.0  21.0   9   7  16
```

**complete-data.txt**

```
2019  11  2 48  45.5745 -29.14132  -71.05508  54.6150 NOEVID          0.215     5.799   8.0  12.0  19.0  23.9   6   6  12
 - CP50  2019  11  2 48  57.169 P           0.601      0.588 
 - CP50  2019  11  2 49   5.164 S           1.472      0.354 
 - CP51  2019  11  2 48  55.744 P           0.254     -0.044 
 - CP51  2019  11  2 49   3.199 S           0.910     -0.250

2019  11 16 46   6.4183 -29.23337  -71.06854   5.0000 NOEVID          0.116     5.612   4.0   5.0  20.0  21.0   9   7  16
 - CP50  2019  11 16 46  16.120 P           0.351      0.097  
 - CP51  2019  11 16 46  15.205 P           0.247     -0.099  
 - CP52  2019  11 16 46  16.950 P           0.382      0.104

2019  12  0 45  30.5744 -29.01455  -71.32178  37.2900 NOEVID          0.093     6.448   7.0   5.0  12.0  14.8  10  10  20
 - C59B  2019  12  0 45  58.219XS           4.500      0.098 
 - CP02  2019  12  0 45  54.504*P           0.691      2.203 
 - CP02  2019  12  0 46   7.929 S           1.412     -0.563
```

**My script:**

```
input="header.txt"
while IFS= read line 
do
   j=$(printf "%s\n" "$line")
   echo "$j"
   sed -n "/$j/,/^ *$/p" complete-data.txt >> new-file.txt
done < "$input"
```

When I run this script, new-file.txt is empty. I tried changing last line:

```
done < "$input" > new-file.txt
```

but the output file is still empty

BUT! if I run it manually:

```
sed -n "/2019  11 16 46   6.4183 -29.23337  -71.06854   5.0000 NOEVID          0.116     5.612   4.0   5.0  20.0  21.0   9   7  16/,/^ *$/p" complete-data.txt >> new-file.txt
```

This Works!!

Comment: Show us a few lines of `header.txt` and matching lines from `complete-data.txt`, with what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: above I show an example of header.txt and complete-data.txt. 
The output I expect is

`2019  11 16 46   6.4183 -29.23337  -71.06854   5.0000 NOEVID          0.116     5.612   4.0   5.0  20.0  21.0   9   7  16
 - CP50  2019  11 16 46  16.120 P           0.351      0.097 
 - CP51  2019  11 16 46  15.205 P           0.247     -0.099  
 - CP52  2019  11 16 46  16.950 P           0.382      0.104`